# My Jquery click button is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hope you well,

I'm trying to make something like this,

firstly, it'll show [this](http://postimg.org/image/dlg57yrdf/)

and after, clicking this "menu" image, It'll show something like [this](http://postimg.org/image/721pkht2x/)

So, I've made some container using `<div>` here:

```
<body>

    //this is my menu container..
    <div class="menu_pos_jquery">
        <a class="btn1" href="#"><img src="logo/menu_logo.png" style="height: 70px; margin-left: 850px; margin-top: 15px;" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Menu" /></a>
    </div>

    //here is my another container which i would like to open using Jquery after click menu container.. 
    <div class="menu_pos_jquery2">

    </div>
</body>
```

So i did tried using this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $(".menu_pos_jquery2").fadeIn();
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $(".menu_pos_jquery2").fadeOut;
    });
    });
</script>
```

But it's not working, When i run this program, but it  shows full page like what i provide you a second pic .. And i want to show only first menu and after click menu it must suppose to show my another container, how to do it? pls, help.. and sorry for my bad English!! .. hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your code into this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu_pos_jquery2").fadeOut();
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $(".menu_pos_jquery2").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, for reply.. but i would like to show as `hidden` first my `second container`.. at the moment it's showing full both the containers..

Comment: Thanks .. now it's now showing.. but another problem is when i click, it shows successfully but now again i do click, it hides and again opens automatically..

Comment: Just to make it clear you want the second `<div>` opened only once ? Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55PpL/)..

Comment: Yes, i want this.. Your Fiddle makes me clear.. thanks for your answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $(".menu_pos_jquery").fadeOut("normal",function(){
            $(".menu_pos_jquery2").fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have registered two `click` event handlers to the same element, so when ever you click the button, both will be called. But only one should be called at a time.

Adding and removing a class to the `.btn` element would be a good option, as you can also specify CSS w.r.t the state. Please consider the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".btn1").click(function(){

        var isMenuOpen = $(this).hasClass("open");

        if(isMenuOpen){

            //if already open, close it
            $(this).removeClass("open");
            $(".menu_pos_jquery2").fadeOut();
        }else {

            //if not open, open it now
            $(this).addClass("open");
            $(".menu_pos_jquery2").fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```